# Use one image to threshold another

Tags: c++, opencv, threshold

I need to apply a threshold to an image in a very specific way, so I came here to see if it is possible.

Say I had two images: one source image, and one threshold image. What I want to is take the source image and use the threshold image to filter it. The operation would compare each pixel of the source image to the threshold image. I the pixel was the same or greater brightness, it would set it to white. If the pixel was less then the brightness, it would set it to black.

Here is an example of what the threshold image might look like:

[image]

Please let me know if I can clarify myself at all.

Thanks!

Comment: A simple [matrix expression](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#matrix-expressions) -- cv::Mat result(a >= b);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple [matrix expression](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#matrix-expressions) will do the job here.

> This is a list of implemented matrix operations that can be combined in arbitrary complex expressions (here `A`, `B` stand for matrices (`Mat`), `s` for a scalar (`Scalar`), `alpha` for a real-valued scalar (`double`)):
>
> ...
>
> Comparison: `A cmpop B`, `A cmpop alpha`, `alpha cmpop A`, where `cmpop` is one of:  `>`, `>=`, `==`, `!=`, `<=`, `<`. The result of comparison is an 8-bit single channel mask whose elements are set to 255 (if the particular element or pair of elements satisfy the condition) or 0.

Hence, something as simple as the following one-liner does what you ask:

```
cv::Mat result(source >= threshold);
```

Comment: Ahh. Why can't it always be that simple in coding? :D